# Как использовать explode(delimiter, string) в запросе MySQL

Tags: mysql

В ячейке есть значение 1234567890_1234567890 и мне необходимо сделать `explode('_', string)['1']`

Как я могу сделать это в запросе?

Answer (score 0):

В MySQL нет функции explode. Если вам надо получить концовку строки после символа подчёркивания - можно делать так:

```sql
SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, '_', -1)
```

Если разделителей может быть несколько - то нужно что-то вроде

```sql
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, '_', 2), '_', -1)
```